# Cocoa windows spawned from Carbon windows are reordered by Mission Control

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-carbon

I have a Carbon-based application that I am migrating to Cocoa. Currently, the application's window is a Carbon window (CaW1). This window creates and displays a Cocoa window (CoW1), which in turn creates and displays another Cocoa Window (CoW2).

When I do this the order of all windows on the screen, from back to front, is as follows:

CaW1
CoW1
CoW2

CoW2 is the top window with CoW1 beneath it and CaW1 at the back. This is the behavior I expect.

Now, when I launch Mission Control in Lion, and click on my app, the windows get reordered. The new ordering is:

CaW1
CoW2
CoW1

The two Cocoa windows have switched places. This behavior is not what I expect. I would have expected CoW2 to remain above CoW1.

I'm trying to understand why this is happening. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

In my Carbon-based app with some Cocoa windows, I've gotten in the habit of adding this to each `NSWindowController` subclass:

```
- (void)windowDidBecomeMain:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    ActivateWindow( (WindowRef) [[self window] windowRef], true );
}
```

It seemed to help with some window ordering issues, but I don't know if it will help with your problem.